# Refresh Filtered Data Extensions automatically

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, filters, ssjs

In our system we have a ftp-triggered automation that imports a file into a data extension that is the source for hundreds of filtered data extensions which will be used for sending (and of course they are scattered around a lot of folders).

What I want to do is refresh all of these filtered data extensions right after the import. As there is no possibility to do so in the automation studio directly, I was thinking about using a ssjs script interaction.

So I made a Landing Page for testing my ssjs code and started retrieving FilterDefinition objects, which worked quite well.
I then wanted to get the ComplexFilter from the FilterDefinition objects, to run it on the source data extension. With the resulting data I was planning to update the target.

My code so far:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1");

    var resultsFD = Email.Retrieve();

    for(var iFD=0; iFD<resultsFD.length; iFD++){
        var filterDef = resultsFD[iFD];
        for(prop in filterDef){
            Write(prop);
            Write(': ');
            Write(filterDef[prop]);
            Write('<br>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

The Output contains the following line:

```
DataFilter: ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.ComplexFilterPart
```

**Here's my problem**:

I can't access this "DataFilter" property properly.

I tried to access it directly, like for example

```
filterDef['DataFilter']['LeftOperand']
```

I also tried using the AmpScript Retrieve function, but it won't work either.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get this property?

Is it possible to access the filter property when using the api from outside the marketing cloud?

Maybe there is a better way to refresh them? If there is a button in MC, so there should be a way to do it, right?

**P.S.:** Using simple Data Filters instead of filtered Data Extension is not an option, because they need to be shared between Business Units.

Thanks a lot for any kind of help

Comment: Why can't you refresh the Filter with a Filter Activity in Automation Studio?

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Unfortunately this means I will have to 1. save the current filtered DE as Data Filter  2. remove existing data extension, 3. add a Filter activity 4. edit created DE to make it sendable. 5. add activity to automation. These steps will multiply by the number of DEs, which is about 280 at the moment. I was hoping there was a simpler solution.